# Remove combobox item from combobox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How to delete combobox item? i tried this code but it does not work.

```
  private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
 foreach (var item in cbRooms.Items)
                {
                    if (((ComboBoxItem)item).Content.ToString() == cbRooms.Text.ToString())
                    {
                        cbRooms.Items.Remove(((ComboBoxItem)item).Content.ToString());
                    }
                }}
```

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint to the `Remove` line and verify that it is actually called, i.e., that the `if` condition actually evaluates to true?

Comment: Why don't you just bind your ComboBox to some collection and remove an item from the collection itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to remove a string try:

```
cbRooms.Items.Remove((ComboBoxItem)item))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the ComboBoxItem rather than:

```
(ComboBoxItem)item).Content.ToString()
```

Try:

```
(item)
```

You may also need to refresh the combo box control after you remove the item:

```
cbRooms.Items.Refresh();
```

**UPDATE**

You could try what kzen said in the comments of the OP. Use a `List<ComboBoxItem>` to store your items, and perform the add/remove operations on the `List`. Then bind the list to your `ComboBox`:

```
cbRooms.ItemsSource = comboBoxItemList;
```

Then when you do your operations on the `List` call the refresh:

```
cbRooms.Items.Refresh();
```

Comment: You could try what kzen said, and use the ItemsSource property to bind your combobox to a List of ComboBoxItems. Make your changes to the List and call the cbRoom.Items.Refresh() once you have done so. Updating the answer to convey this.